# Proc and logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, proc

I am trying to log some variables inside a Proc method, but its not writing to the log file.

```
Rails.logger.info("testing")
Proc.new do
  Rails.logger.info("testing again")
end
```

It only prints testing in the log file.

Also I tried to write a new log file inside the Proc process, again it doesn't do anything.

```
Rails.logger.info("testing")
Proc.new do
  log = Logger.new('proc.log')
  log.info('testing')
end
```

Please help me to log the variables or explain how I can inspect them inside from Proc process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is because Proc itself doesn't execute the code, but just returns the code block as an object. So you need to call this object.

```
Rails.logger.info("testing")
my_proc = Proc.new do
  Rails.logger.info("testing again")
end
my_proc.call
```

[Proc in Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html)